# i am a ubuntu user with dual boot , does deleting some large files from system volume information cause some problms while using windows 7

Tags: windows-7, system

when i am using ubuntu i see a large file on my partition which has windows 7 installed on it...
 the file has a name- 
{727a267e-992c-11e1-b9f7-00235aa5eeaf}{3808876b-c176-4e48-b7ae-04046e6cc752}
in the folder system volume information and its occupying a size of 4.5 GB...
i want to get rid of it..so that i can use that space...
there is also a similar named file but it is only taking some KBs..so it doesn't concern me
i have not tried deleting the 4.5 GB one because i want to know-if it safe to delete this file ...i know that it will not cause any problems in ubuntu...but is it safe to delete it if i want my windows 7 to run properly
plz help me on this

Comment: This question is off-topic here

Comment: As it is an issue with Windows 7 you may get better answers there: http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an Ubuntu user I frequently delete the Windows folder "System Volume Information" and no harm is done. But if you use Windows, it automatically re-creates this folder to store some system information which in Windows drive/partition may also include "System Restore" files. I believe by deleting them you merely prevent Windows from going back in time ;-) I know this only for Windows XP though, not Windows 7.
You might perhaps move or rename that folder, and see what happens before completely deleting it.

Comment: @Sadi-thank you...but i don't want to delete the whole folder...i just want to delete a particular file which is occupying 4.5 gb and it is not in the restore folder